# Spring Could not Resolve placeholder

Tags: java, spring

I'm fairly new to spring so excuse me if this is a dumb question. When I try to launch a program I get the following error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'appclient' in string value [${appclient}]`. The error is thrown when the following code is executed:

```
package ca.virology.lib2.common.config.spring.properties;
import ca.virology.lib2.config.spring.PropertiesConfig;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@Import({PropertiesConfig.class})
@PropertySource("${appclient}")
public class AppClientProperties {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppClientProperties.class);
{
    //this initializer block will execute when an instance of this class is created by Spring
    log.info("Loading AppClientProperties");
}
@Value("${appclient.port:}")
private int appClientPort;

@Value("${appclient.host:}")
private String appClientHost;

public int getAppClientPort() {
    return appClientPort;
}

public String getAppClientHost() {
    return appClientHost;
}
}
```

A property file called `appclient.properties` exists in the resources folder with the information for host and port. I'm not sure where the `"${appclient}"` is defined, if it is at all. Maybe it is not even defined and that is causing the problem. Do I need to change the `"${appclient}"` to something like `"{classpath:/appclient.properties}"` or am I missing something else?

Comment: You could reference the PropertySource using classpath sure: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

Comment: I was actually trying to run this program, name it 'B' within a different program, named 'A'. Apparently when you execute the program B individually, it gets the `${appclient}` value as a program argument; however, that didn't happen when I try to run B from A and caused the error I was getting.

Comment: If you have multiple properties files and all the properties files have the same key, the issue occurs. If yes use the profile parameter while starting the app.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are not reading the properties file correctly. The propertySource should pass the parameter as: `file:appclient.properties` or `classpath:appclient.properties`. Change the annotation to:

```
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:appclient.properties"})
```

However I don't know what your `PropertiesConfig` file contains, as you're importing that also. Ideally the `@PropertySource` annotation should have been kept there.

Answer (score 15):

Hopefully it will be still helpful, the application.properties (or application.yml) file must be in both the paths:

- src/main/resource/config
- src/test/resource/config

containing the same property you are referring

Comment: It works , but can someone explain the underlying logic behind this ?

Answer (score 13):

If you are using Spring 3.1 and above, you can use something like...

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties")
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
  return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
}
```

You can also go by the xml configuration like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties" />

  </beans>
```

In earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

In my case , I forgot to add the new property in my application.properties under test folder.Adding it resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

If your config file is in a different path than classpath, you can add the configuration file path as a system property:

```
java -Dapp.config.path=path_to_config_file -jar your.jar
```

Comment: It works! 
java -Xdebug -Dct.ctconfig.consul.server=http://{Your QA IP}:8355 -Dspring.profiles.active=qa -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=8200,suspend=n -jar build/libs/YourAppJar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Answer (score 1):

[image]I know It is an old message , but i want to add my case.

**If you use more than one profile(dev,test,prod...), check your execute profile.**

Answer (score 0):

For properties that need to be managed outside of the WAR:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:///C:/application.yml"/>
```

For example if inside application.yml are `name` and `id`

Then you can create bean in runtime inside xml spring

```
<bean id="id1" class="my.class.Item">
    <property name="name" value="${name}"/>
    <property name="id" value="${id}"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the war file generated didn't pick up the properties file so had to clean install again in IntelliJ editor.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue occurs in IntelliJ, all you have to do is to install the plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7861-envfile and follow the steps given.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow for me the error was due to missing library slf4j-api. After I added following library the error went away

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score -13):

My solution was to add a space between the $ and the {.

For example:

```
@Value("${appclient.port:}")
```

becomes

```
@Value("$ {appclient.port:}")
```

Comment: For anyone running into this, this will not work. Adding a space will just mean @Value parses the string directly (so the final value becomes `$ {appclient.port:}` instead of, say, `12345`).

Comment: yes, that's because it turns into a string and not a template placeholder.