# Spring - Could not resolve placeholder

Tags: java, spring

My code, which is working earlier is not working suddenly and I am getting below error.

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'TABLE_DETAILS_CONCURRENT_CONSUMERS'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:272)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:75)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:599)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:398)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
```

***Note: This question is not duplicate to existing questions in stackoverflow*** since I have tried all suggestions

[Could not resolve Spring property placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779572/could-not-resolve-spring-property-placeholder)

[Spring Could not Resolve placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307237/spring-could-not-resolve-placeholder)

[Could not resolve placeholder in string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244696/could-not-resolve-placeholder-in-string-value)

[spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and context:property-placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542506/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-and-contextproperty-placeholder)

I have

1. One instance of

   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
2. ignore-unresolved-placeholders is set to true

but still I am getting same error.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

     <context:property-placeholder location="file:/home/pg/myapp/conf/pds_config.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>
     <bean class="com.baseapp.pds.PDSInitializer" factory-method="createConfiguration">
        <constructor-arg value="/home/pg/myapp/conf/pds_config.properties"></constructor-arg>
     </bean>
     <bean class="com.baseapp.pds.sc.SC" init-method="init"/>
     <bean class="com.baseapp.pds.PDSInitializer" factory-method="initDomain">
     </bean>


</beans>
```

XML2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:si="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration" 
    xmlns:si-jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <context:property-placeholder location="file:/home/pg/baseapp/conf/pgconfig-serviceregistry.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
```

Spring version : 3.0.0

Comment: can you show the code

Comment: Updated question

Comment: You say "ignore-unresolved-placeholders is set to true", but in your XML it's different: ignore-resource-not-found is set to true. unresolved placeholders != resource not found

Comment: 'ignore-unresolved-placeholders' is not allowed to appear in element 'context:property-placeholder' error has come and hence changed to resource not found