# Spring boot 2.7.18 and spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud

I  am trying to upgrade spring boot from 2.5.12 to 2.7.18 and spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes from 1.1.2.RELEASE. With old versions I have application running and there is no any issue. Initially I have following in pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.15</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

After update I have this 2 dependencies for kubernetes, the rest is the same

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>kubernetes-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And I am getting issue

```
Error creating bean ...: Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder...
```

how this can be fixed?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring, but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307237/spring-could-not-resolve-placeholder) can help you